# Redirecionamento com timer e localStorage

Tags: javascript

Estou tentado fazer um código em JS e quando eu entro na página `index.html` redireciona para página `teste.html` e na teste irei clicar em um fechar onde vai voltar para index e no caso agora tem que ficar na index, então um contador de tempo irá executar novamente o código de *redirect* para `teste.html`

Segue meu código abaixo..

```
function openColorBox() {
  window.location.href = 'teste.html';
}

function countDown() {
  seconds—
  $("#seconds").text(seconds);
  if (seconds === 5) {
    openColorBox();
    clearInterval(i);
  }
}

var seconds = 5,
    i = setInterval(countDown, 2 * 420000);
```

Outra tentativa

```
function openColorBox() {
  window.location.href = 'landing.html';
}

function countDown() {
  seconds—
  $("#seconds").text(seconds);
  if (seconds === 5) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("hora") - Date.now() > time_restart) {
      localStorage.setItem("hora", Date.now());
      openColorBox();
    }
    clearInterval(i);
  }
}

var seconds = 5,
    i = setInterval(countDown, 2 * 420000);
```

Comment: Mas para que serve a página index?

Comment: a index tem o site.. no caso o teste.html seria uma propaganda. Que vai abrir a cada  x time... se tu  ficar na index.html no caso

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado do seu código? O que ele está fazendo que falta fazer ou que não deveria?

Comment: Ele abre a teste.html no tempo definido mas eu gostaria q abrisse quando entra no site e dps sempre no tempo definido, e no caso abrir a primeira vez que não e depois dar um settimout q não estou conseguindo fazer